# Irreducible over $C[x,y]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

I want to show that $$f=x^4+2y^2x^2+yx+5y$$ is irreducible over $\mathbb C[x,y]$.

My answer is,
$f$ is in $\mathbb C[x,y]=\mathbb C[y][x]$, and let $R=\mathbb C[y]$, then $f$ is irreducible over $\mathbb C[y]$ (because if we let $c=y$, then $2y^2$, $y$, $5y$ is divisible by $c$, but $1$ is not divisible by $c$, and $5y$ is not divisible by $c^2$).

I don't know how to do next, but in my guess, $\mathbb C$ is $\text{UFD},$ so $\mathbb C[y]=R$ is also $\text{UFD}.$ And $f$ in $R[x]$ is primitive(Since $f$ is monic), and so on $\dots$

Is there any proposition about relation between this primitive, and irreducible?

Thank you!

Comment: Typeset mathematical terms using MathJax. [Here's the tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Oh, thank you! I editted :)

Comment: I’m not sure I understand your question. Any factorisation of $f$ in $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ is a factorization in $\mathbb{C}[y][x]$, so Eisenstein (which you did) should be enough?

Comment: umm.. What I proved is that given polynomial is irreducible over $C[y]$, but I want to show it is also irreducible over $C[y][x]=C[x,y]$. I want to connect this two, but I don't know how to relate it..

Comment: If you look at it as a polynomial *over* $\mathbb C[x,y]$, then it's a constant polynomial, so it's the same as irreducible *in* $\mathbb C[x,y]$, by the degree argument.